# Is it possible for a variable to evaluate to a multi-dimensional PHP array index

Tags: php, arrays

Given a multidimensional array or dictionary `$array`.

And assuming that `$array['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'something';`

Is there a way other than via an eval statement for me use the multi-dimentional index `foo/bar/baz`? (The use case is in creating the index dynamically i.e. The function does not know what /foo/bar/baz/ is).

The only way I could figure to do this was:

```
$item = testGetIndex($array, "'foo']['bar']['baz'");

function testGetIndex($array, $index) {
  eval('$item = $array[' . $index . '];');
  return $item;
}
```

---

**Note**:
I should mention that I do not want to search this array.  This is a weird use case.  I am being passed a very large multi dimensional array and it's ugly to have to use constructs like..

`$array[foo][bar]..[baz]` to make modifications to the array.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question but sounds like you are looking for searching in arrays with something like `array_search`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting config ini like string dot separated value to actual array keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086423/converting-config-ini-like-string-dot-separated-value-to-actual-array-keys)

Comment: `eval` is what separates scripting from compiled languages, and perfectly fine for cases as such; as long as you know what you are doing (no unvetted input). The manual traversal methods work just as well, but when you say "make modifications", you will need a reference-wise traversing approach.

Comment: @mario Yeah, I do like my simple to understand eval strategy but I've been warned never to use eval for anything.  I was hoping the PHP had an array function to do this for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify an array using a path:

```
function setPath(&$root, $path, $value)
{
        $paths = explode('/', $path);
        $current = &$root;

        foreach ($paths as $path) {
                if (isset($current[$path])) {
                        $current = &$current[$path];
                } else {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        return $current = $value;
}
$path = 'foo/bar/baz';
$root = array('foo' => array('bar' => array('baz' => 'something')));

setPath($root, $path, '123');
```

You can tweak the function to just return a reference to the element you wish to change:

```
function &getPath(&$root, $path)
{
        $paths = explode('/', $path);
        $current = &$root;

        foreach ($paths as $path) {
                if (isset($current[$path])) {
                        $current = &$current[$path];
                } else {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        return $current;
}

$x = &getPath($root, $path);

$x = 456; // $root['foo']['bar']['baz'] == 456
```

Answer (score 2):

Blatently reusing [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086423/converting-config-ini-like-string-dot-separated-value-to-actual-array-keys/16086531#16086531):

```
function recurseKeys(array $keys,array $array){
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if(!isset($array[$key])) return null;
    return empty($keys) ?
        $array[$key]:
        recurseKeys($keys,$array[$key];
}
$values = recurseKeys(explode('/','foo/bar/baz'),$yourArray);
```

**edit:** as Jack pointed out, recursion is not needed:

```
function findByKey(array $keys,array $array){
    while(!is_null($key = array_shift($keys))){
        if(!isset($array[$key])) return null;
        $array = $array[$key];
    }
    return $array;
}
$values = findByKey(explode('/','foo/bar/baz'),$yourArray);
```

Comment: Why recursion? This problem can be easily expressed iteratively.

Comment: Turns out we both had it wrong, because OP wants a way to make modifications on the array rather than finding the value.

Comment: @jack: well references to the rescue then... made the exact alteration you just posted, so I just won't bother ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop can make it, like:

```
function get(array $array, $keys) {
  $val = $array;
  foreach (explode('/', $keys) as $part) {
    if (!isset($val[$part])) {
      return null;
    }
    $val = $val[$part];
  }
  return $val;
}

$array['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'something';
echo get($array, 'foo/bar/baz');
```

http://ideone.com/vcRvXW

**Edit**:

For modification, just use references:

```
function set(array &$array, $keys, $value) {
  $val = &$array;
  foreach (explode('/', $keys) as $part) {
    if (!isset($val[$part])) {
      $val[$part] = array();
    }
    $val = &$val[$part];
  }
  $val = $value;
}
```

http://ideone.com/WUNhF6

Comment: Apparently, OP needs function to modify array rather than just reading it.